# Matplotlib Histogram plot : limiting x axis with max value without ignoring records that exceeds that value

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, histogram

I have a list of around 30k values to plot into a matplotlib histogram , most of the values are between 1 and 500, which makes the bars in that area range clearly visible and bars above 500 nearly invisible (you can see attached photo)
I want to limit x axis to a max value (like 1000) but without ignoring the list values that are above 1000, is there a way to limit the histogram to 1000 (plt.xlim(xmax=1000)) but without ignoring values greater than 1000 (we add a last bar in the histogram that show the cumulus of all list values greater than 1000)

Here is the code:

```
commutes =  pd.Series( (v for v in nb_posts_user_list) ) # nb_posts_user_list contain around 30k values between 1 and 3000
binwidth=10
commutes.plot.hist(grid=True,color='r', alpha=0.5, label='x',bins=range(min(commutes), max(commutes) + binwidth, binwidth))
plt.xlim(xmin=0)
#plt.xlim(xmax=1000)
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
#plt.xlabel('Average tweet length (Number of char)')
plt.xlabel(xlabel)
plt.ylabel(ylabel)
plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.75)
plt.show()
```

I am getting this histogram

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only way you have is to limit the bins, so, instead of `max(commutes` in `bins=range(min(commutes), max(commutes) + binwidth, binwidth)` you'd better select a lower value (1000).

Other way could be describing your y values in a different (logarithmic?) scale.